# Does prepending "http://" to a user-provided string yield a safe-to-use URL?

Tags: xss

Is it safe (in terms of XSS vulnerability) to get a parameter X from the user, escape its double-quotations and insert it as href?

```
Pseudo-code:
Y = escape_double_quotes(X);
print '<a href="http://' + Y + '">link</a>'
```

Answer (score 2):

(The following answer is based on the assumption that `escape_double_quotes()` only escapes quotation marks.)

It depends on whether the user who is providing the parameter is different from the user who is seeing the link. If a user A is providing the parameter, but another user B may see the resulting link, then user A might maliciously insert a link to exploit user B. Consider the following example:

`www.example.com/transfer_money.php?src=userB&dest=userA`, which would result in:

`print '<a href="http://www.example.com/transfer_money.cgi?src=userA&dest=userB">link</a>'`

Another example:

`></a><a href=javascript:myfunc()`, which results in:

`print '<a href="http://" ></a><a href=javascript:myfunc()>link</a>'`

Comment: In such a scenario, the link is not considered to be the vulnerability. The attack should (and must) be defended using CSRF tokens. Good try, though! :D

Comment: See the new example.

Comment: Oops, my bad, I had a typo in the pseudo-code. Your second example won't work either.

Comment: With your edited pseudo-code, assuming a correct implementation of `escape_double_quotes()`, I don't see a glaringly easy exploit. That being said, I don't see why you wouldn't just escape all potentially dangerous characters. An exploit may be possible if, for instance, a browser attempts to be helpful and "fixes" what it sees as broken anchor tags.